# Apps Script: Change or modify bold, foreground color and style in general (TypeError: format.getTextStyle is not a function) - Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have the following definition:

```
format = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
        .setForegroundColor(spec.textColor)
        .setBold(spec.bold)
        .build();
```

I want to modify it, but I have not been able so far. Some examples of unlucky attempts:

The following, returns the error: *TypeError: format.setForegroundColor is not a function*: `format.setForegroundColor("green");`

The following, returns the error: *TypeError: format.getTextStyle is not a function*: `format.getTextStyle().setForegroundColor("yellow");`

The following does nothing: `format.setForegroundColor = "green";`

The following DO work, but it does not seem a proper/elegant solution (as we are basically creating the variable again instead modifying a value of it):

```
format = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
        .setForegroundColor("green")
        .setBold(spec.bold)
        .build();
```

How to properly modify the foreground color or bold attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot modify a [`TextStyle`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-style) once its been built. The built-in `SpreadsheetApp` service creates `TextStyle` instances by employing the [Builder design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) which generally produces an immutable object as a final result. So you can't invoke the methods you used in the build process on the final object.

However, you can generate a new [`TextStyleBuilder`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-style-builder) from an existing `TextStyle` by using the [`TextStyle::copy()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-style#copy) function.

```js
const textStyleBuilderA = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle();
const textStyleA = textStyleBuilderA
        .setForegroundColor(spec.textColor)
        .setBold(spec.bold)
        .build();

const textStyleBuilderB = textStyleA.copy();
// Note that you only need to change the foreground color
// since the bold setting is inherited
const textStyleB = textStyleBuilderB
        .setForegroundColor('green')
        .build();
```